# Integral with analytical solution with normal distribution

Tags: statistics, integration, probability-distributions

I received very good answers a couple of days ago in a simpler related problem, see [Integral with Normal Distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36348/integral-with-normal-distributions), but I am struggling with this new question:

Let's define a function $F(\theta)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Phi  \left(\theta -a- b x\right) \phi\left(cx- \theta \right) \mathrm d x$

$\theta$ is a relevant parameter and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all given scalars. $\Phi$ and $\phi$ respectively denote the CDF and PDF of the standard normal distribution

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to express analytically this integral as a function of $\theta$, $a$, $b$ and $c$? (The case with $a=0$, $b=c=1$ is the one solved in the previous question)
2. I want to find conditions on $a$, $b$ and $c$ that make $F'(\theta)<1$.

Comment: I am trying to solve a more complicated problem, and knowing the answer to these questions would make my life much easier. I don't know whether nice solutions can be found.

Comment: Are there any relationships among $a,b,c$ and $\theta$, or restrictions to appropriate ranges? It might help a great deal here...

Comment: @J.M. Unfortunately not... everything can be on real line...

Comment: So, $c$ can be negative (the case not covered in Shai's answer) for instance?

Comment: @J.M. I apologize. $c>0$ is fine for my purposes (I just checked my $c$ in the large problem that I am trying to solve and it is positive). In general it would correspond to $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ when standardizing the distribution.

Comment: Though (now) not relevant, the case $c < 0$ follows by a change of variable $x \mapsto -x$; for $c = 0$ the integral diverges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $a,b,\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c > 0$, it holds
$$
F(\theta ) := \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\Phi (\theta  - a - bx)\phi (cx - \theta )\,{\rm d}x} = \frac{1}{c}\Phi \bigg(\frac{{(c - b)\theta  - ac}}{{\sqrt {c^2  + b^2 } }}\bigg).
$$
(I confirmed the result numerically.)

**Proof.** First note that
$$
\frac{1}{c}\Phi \bigg(\frac{{(c - b)\theta  - ac}}{{\sqrt {c^2  + b^2 } }}\bigg) = \frac{1}{c}{\rm P}\bigg[Z \le \frac{{(c - b)\theta  - ac}}{{\sqrt {c^2  + b^2 } }}\bigg] = \frac{1}{c}{\rm P}\big[cX + bY \le (c - b)\theta  - ac\big],
$$
where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent ${\rm N}(0,1)$ random variables (note that $\sqrt {c^2  + b^2 } Z$ and $cX+bY$ are identically distributed). By the law of total probability, conditioning on $Y$, we thus get
$$
\frac{1}{c}\Phi \bigg(\frac{{(c - b)\theta  - ac}}{{\sqrt {c^2  + b^2 } }}\bigg) = \frac{1}{c}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{\rm P}\big[cX + by \le (c - b)\theta  - ac\big]\phi (y)\,{\rm d}y}. 
$$
A change of variable $y=cx-\theta$ then gives
$$
\frac{1}{c}\Phi \bigg(\frac{{(c - b)\theta  - ac}}{{\sqrt {c^2  + b^2 } }}\bigg) = \frac{1}{c}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{\rm P}\big[cX + b(cx - \theta ) \le (c - b)\theta  - ac\big]\phi (cx - \theta )c\,{\rm d}x} . 
$$
A little algebra shows that the expression on the right is equal to
$$
\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{\rm P}\big[X \le  \theta  - a -bx \big]\phi (cx - \theta )\,{\rm d}x},
$$
and hence 
$$
\frac{1}{c}\Phi \bigg(\frac{{(c - b)\theta  - ac}}{{\sqrt {c^2  + b^2 } }}\bigg) = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\Phi (\theta  - a - bx)\phi (cx - \theta )\,{\rm d}x}. 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It makes my life much easier.