# Distribution of the normal cdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am wondering what is the probability density function for the normal cdf $\Phi (aX+b)$, where $\phi$ is the usual standard normal cumulative distribution function

I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\Phi(aX+b)]$ but i am stuck on how to get the distribution. thank you =]

note: X is normally distributed

Comment: What does $X$ stand for?  Where does the problem come from?

Comment: X is a random variable, I thought it up, trying to calculate the expected value of a cumulative distribution

Comment: The expected value of a *function* $f(X)$ of a random variable $X$ depends in general on the distribution of $X$, and not only the mean of $X$. There was no specification made in the post about the distribution of $X$, only about what $f$ was.

Comment: oops hehe, thanks for reminding me =]

Comment: X is normally distributed

Comment: Convnetionally the capital $\Phi$ is the cdf and the lower-case $\varphi$ is the density function.  This posting says "where $\phi$ is the[...]cumulative distribution function", after an expression that uses $\Phi$, not $\phi$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the standard normal random variables. Then 
$$
 \mathbb{E}(\Phi(a X + b)) = \mathbb{E}( \mathbb{P}( Y \le a x + b \vert X = x ) ) = \mathbb{P}(Y- a X \le b )
$$
But the combination $Z = Y-a X$ also follows normal distribution (being a linear combination of normals), with zero mean and variance $\mathbb{E}((Y-a X)^2) = 1 + a^2$. Hence
$$
 \mathbb{E}(\Phi(a X + b)) = \Phi\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right) 
$$

Here is numerical checks:

```
In[14]:= With[{a = 3., 
  b = 1/2}, {NExpectation[CDF[NormalDistribution[], a x + b], 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]],
  CDF[NormalDistribution[], b/Sqrt[1 + a^2]]}]

Out[14]= {0.562816, 0.562816}
```

Comment: how do you get the first equality? thanks

Comment: @JessC The first equality is the definition of the cumulative density function, namely $\Phi(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \le y )$.

Comment: +1 indeed!  But may I request that the first inequality be expanded out a little e.g. as in $$E[\Phi(aX+b)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(ax+b)\phi(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(Y \leq aX + b\mid X = x)\phi(x)dx = P(Y \leq aX + b)\ldots...$$ so as to make the connection very clear?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, I agree this would add clarity. I will be able to make the change only in few hours from now. Thanks for the comment and the upvote