# Does $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x)\phi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)\,dx $ have a closed form solution?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

Is there a solution to the following Integral that can get rid of the integral, but can leave the answer in terms of $\Phi()$ (the standard normal CDF) and $\phi $ (the standard normal PDF).?

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x)\phi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)\,dx  $$

where $a, b$ are constants with $b>0$,

I've tried several variants of integration by parts, all of which get me nowhere. I'm thinking the likely answer is no.

Comment: Do you want the result in terms of $\Phi$, which does not exist in closed form?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I meant closed form as in get rid of the integral; i.e. $\int \Phi(x)dx = x\Phi(x)+\phi(x)$

Comment: It seems the answer should be $\frac{1}{2b}$ as the mean doesn't matter as $x \to \infty$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. That also doesn't seem to coincide with some numerical integration examples I ran.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74770/321264

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integral in question can be given an probabilistic interpretation:
$$ \begin{split}
   \int_\mathbb{R} \Phi(x) \phi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right) \mathrm{d}x &= b \int_\mathbb{R} \Pr(Z \leqslant x) \phi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{b} \\ &= b \int_\mathbb{R} \Pr(Z \leqslant a+b y) \phi\left(y\right) \mathrm{d}y \\ &=
   b \Pr\left(Z \leqslant a + b Y \right) = b \Pr\left(Z - b Y \leqslant a \right)
\end{split} $$
Since $Z$ and $Y$ are both independent standard normal random variables, $Z-b Y$ is also a normal random variables, with mean and variance:
$$
    \mathbb{E}(Z-b Y) = 0, \quad \mathbb{Var}(Z-b Y) = \mathbb{Var}(Z) + b^2 \mathbb{Var}(Y) = 1+b^2
$$
Thus $Z- b Y \stackrel{d}{=} X$, where $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sqrt{1+b^2} \right)$ we have:
$$
  \int_\mathbb{R} \Phi(x) \phi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right) \mathrm{d}x = b \Pr\left(Z - b Y \leqslant a \right) = b \Pr\left(X \leqslant a \right) = b \, \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right) \tag{1}
$$
Numerical check of $(1)$:

```
In[25]:= With[{a = -3., 
  b = 2.3}, {NIntegrate[
   CDF[NormalDistribution[], x] PDF[
     NormalDistribution[], (x - a)/b], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], 
  b CDF[NormalDistribution[], a/Sqrt[1 + b^2]]}]

Out[25]= {0.266371, 0.266371}
```

Comment: +1, obviously the way to go. (I seem to remember having explained this on the site relatively recently.)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I must admit I'm having a little hard time following, especially where you have $ b \int Pr(Z \leq a+by)      \phi(y) dy=bPr(Z \leq a+bY) $. Could you elaborate on that step a bit?

Comment: @Greg It makes use of the definition for the expectation $\int f(y) \phi(y) \mathrm{d}y = \mathbb{E}(f(Y))$ and the law of total expectation: $ b \int \Pr(Z \leqslant a+b y) \phi(y) \mathrm{d}y = \mathbb{E}\left( \Pr(Z \leqslant a+b Y \mid Y) \right) = \Pr( Z \leqslant a+b Y )$.