# Prove that $ \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } \phi (ax) \Phi(bx)\,dx = \frac{1}{2|a|}$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We have normal PDF and CDF of Gaussian $\phi (x)$ and $\Phi(x)$.

How can I prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } \phi (ax) \Phi(bx)\,dx = \frac{1}{2|a|}?$$

---

What I have tried

Left side can be written as $$\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(ax)^2}{2}} \Phi(bx)\,dx$$

and failed to open up the $\Phi(bx)$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Show by differentiation that the value of the integral does not depend on $b$ and compute the integral for a specific value of $b$.

Comment: Are you saying that we can say the integral on the left hand side does not depend on b as differentiation of the right hand side does not have b?

Comment: Differentiate the integral with respect to $b$ and show that the resulting integral is identically zero. Thus, the original integral must be a constant function of $b$.

Comment: @gary Now I understand that the original integral is a constant function. Thank you. How  can I lead the value of $b$ from there?

Comment: Choose $b=0$ for example.

Comment: Thank you. Now I completely understand

Comment: Easier method: observe that $\Phi(bx)=\Phi(bx)-{1 \over 2}+{1\over 2}$ and that $\Phi(bx)-{1\over 2}$ is antisymmetric, hence its integral with  $\phi(ax)$ will vanish.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376586/321264.