# How to compute the integral $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(x\right)\left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, special-functions, error-function

I am trying to integrate the product of the standard normal CDF ($\Phi(x)$) and a shifted and scaled normal survival function (SF) given by $1-\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$, i.e. the following:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(x\right)\left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]\mathrm{d}x$$

where $\mu, \sigma > 0$. I figured this could be made equivalent to the integration of $\mathrm{erf}(x)\cdot\mathrm{erfc}((x-\mu)/\sigma)$, however looking in the D.B. Owen *Table of Normal Integrals* or the M. Geller *Table of Integrals of the Error Functions* didn't turn up anything applicable. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting
$$ f \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}, \, f(\mu,\sigma) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x) \left[1 - \Phi \left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)\right] \, \mathrm{d} x \, , $$
denote your integral, we have
$$ \partial_1 f(\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma} \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x) \phi \left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right) \, \mathrm{d} x = \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right) .$$
Here $\phi$ is the standard normal PDF and the last step follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376586/does-int-infty-infty-phix-phi-left-fracx-ab-right-dx-have-a?noredirect=1) question. Since $x \mapsto x \Phi(x) + \phi(x)$ is an antiderivative of $\Phi$ (and $f(-\infty,\sigma) = 0$), we obtain
$$ f(\mu,\sigma) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\mu \Phi\left(\frac{\nu}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right) \, \mathrm{d} \nu = \mu \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right) + \sqrt{1 + \sigma^2} \phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right) .$$

Comment: Thanks so much! This was great help.