# How to demonstrate that integral of N $\int$ N is equal to integral of N($\sigma$) incremented?

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Recently, I have drawn the 2 following functions

$$
f(x) = \int_{t=-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(N(t\mid x,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}).\int_{y=Limit}^{+\infty} N(y\mid t,\sigma^2) \, dy \,\right)\, dt
$$

and
$$
g(x) = \int_{y=Limit}^{+\infty} N(y\mid x,\sigma^2(\frac{n+1}{n})) \, dy
$$

where

$$
N(x\mid\mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}
$$ is the density function of a normal distribution.

On a graph, when $\mu$, $\sigma$, $n$ and $Limit$ are known, these 2 functions are full equal for all $x$ between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$

Question: how can I explain that these 2 functions are equivalent using pure mathematical expression ?

Just to help others, this formula is equivalent (but not equal) to integral described in
[How to compute normal integrals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(x)N(x\mid\mu,\sigma^2)\,dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(x)N(x\mid\mu,\sigma^2)x\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539472/how-to-compute-normal-integrals-int-infty-infty-phixnx-mid-mu-sigma2?rq=1)

Comment: You can get proper parentheses that adjust to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: It looks like your $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ functions have no dependence on $x$.

Comment: @joriki: I have changed the parentheses for first formula. It is good for you ?

Comment: @Michael: you have right. I will take 10 minutes to correct both functions.

Comment: That made the first one a lot more readable -- but you have several more parentheses that are way too small. Also the square root doesn't contain its argument; you need to enclose the argument in braces `{}` to fix that. (Also there's no need to put it in parentheses when it's already inside a square root.)

Comment: @joriki: I have enhanced square root display

Comment: @Michael: I have corrected the functions.

Comment: It suffices to prove that for all $x,y$ you have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} N(t | x, \sigma^2/n) N(y|t, \sigma^2)dt = N(y|x, (n+1)\sigma^2/n)$, which you can do by completing the square.

Comment: Or in the integral you can do the change of variables $u=t-x, du=dt$, to reduce it to a convolution of two Gaussian densities evaluated at $x-y$.

Comment: ...And there is even a nice probabilistic interpretation of the identity in terms of random variables which allows to prove (and understand) it with almost no computations.