# Integral of Gaussian function

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

I have the following integral. Let $\phi(x)$ be the p.d.f. and $\Phi(x)$ the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution. For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, let

\begin{equation}
G(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^x \Phi(au+b) \phi(u) du.
\end{equation}

Can one solve this integral for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$? In this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74770/distribution-of-the-normal-cdf), it is shown that $G(\infty)=\Phi(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}})$. The list of integrals on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) also does not include this particular case.

Comment: What do you mean by solving the integral? The c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution itself cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: The integral is equivalent to the probability $\Pr\{X \leq x, Y \leq aX + b\}$ and it cannot be expressed in terms of the univariate normal CDF/pdf, except for those trivial cases.

Comment: @Kavi, by solving I mean expressing $G(x)$ in terms of $\Phi$ and $\phi$ without the integral.

Comment: @BGM, can you give an explanation or reference, why this cannot be done? You mean there is no expression of $G(x)$ without the integral?

Comment: @BGM, oh I get it, i can only express is it in terms of a bivariate cdf... Thank you!