# Calculate $E[\Phi(aX+b)^n]$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am working on a project, where this expected value shows up again and again, where $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal distribution.
$$E[\Phi(aX+b)^n]$$
However, I have not yet been able to solve it.

I am aware of the solution if $n=1$, given for instance in the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74770/distribution-of-the-normal-cdf?noredirect=1&lq=1).
I am also aware that if $a=1$ and $b=0$, then $\Phi(X)$ would be uniformly distributed and it would then be easy to find.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: This question has been studied many times by communications engineers under the name "$M$-ary orthogonal signaling" where the expectation is the probability that a receiver correctly determines which of $n+1$ orthogonal signals has been transmitted. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/544706/6633) and its answers on stats.SE as well as [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43705/6633) which looks at the complementary probability (prob. of incorrect determination) which is much harder to compute accurately. The expectation here much easier to evaluate numerically.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you very much for your comment. I went to look at your answer to the other question. There, I saw that you linked to some lecture notes, which you thought could be helpful. Unfortunately, that link does not refer to anything. Can you please update the link?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the link.

Comment: The new link you added works, but the links to the pdf-files on the web page do not work. 
I am sorry, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @DilipSarwate I added two answsers to the two questions in [Cross Validated site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43685/which-is-largest-of-a-bunch-of-normally-distributed-random-variables/627015#627015). In fact, we can have closed-form expression via a multivariate normal probability for these two questions as well.

Comment: @JakobLarsen Just for information, the multivariate normal probability cannot be analytically computed, but there are many modern numerical methods for the fast computation (for example: Genz which is implemented in almost all software such as Matlab, Python, Fortran,... ). However, for this particular expectation, if you want to have a fast computation, I believe the fastest method is to numerically compute it via an integral of dimension $1$ (without using the multivariate normal probability that I gave you in the answer).

Comment: @NN2 Thank you for the comment. 
Maybe it is a dumb question from my side, but as I see it, the only problem that might arise is computational problems, and I don't expect that to be a problem. Are there any other problems that might arise when using functions that cannot be computed analytically?

Comment: @JakobLarsen the only problem that I know that there may be some numerical errors (these errors can be reduced by increasing the number of discretization, hence the computation times will increase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us denote $(Y_i)_{i=1,..,n}$ the $n$ i.i.d random variables following the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and are independent to $X$. We have
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\Phi^n(aX+b))& = \mathbb{E}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(Y_i\le aX+b|X)  \right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_i\le aX+b  \}}|X)  \right)\tag{1}
\end{align}$$

We know that, if $Y, Z$ are independent to each other, then
$$ \mathbb{E}(Y)\cdot  \mathbb{E}(Z) = \mathbb{E}(YZ)   \tag{2}$$

Given $X$, these random variables $\left(\mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_i\le aX+b  \}}|X  \right)_{i=1,..,n}$ are independent to each other. Then, we apply $(2)$ to $(1)$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\Phi^n(aX+b))&= \mathbb{E}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_i\le aX+b  \}}|X)  \right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left( \mathbb{E}\left(\left.\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_i\le aX+b  \}}\right|X\right)  \right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left( \mathbb{E}\left(\left.\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_i-aX\le b  \}}\right|X\right)  \right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left( \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_i-aX\le b  \}} \right) \\
&=  \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{ Y_i-aX\le b  \}\right) \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Let us denote $Z_i = Y_i -aX$ for $i =1,..,n$. Then $(Z_i)_{i=1,...,n}$ follows the multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}_n(\mathbf{0}_n;\Sigma)$ avec
$$\Sigma_{ij} = \text{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        a^2+1 & \mbox{if } i=j \\
        a^2 & \mbox{if } i\ne j \\
    \end{array} \right. \tag{4}
$$
From $(3)$, we deduce that

$$\color{red}{\mathbb{E}(\Phi^n(aX+b)) = \Phi_n \left(\mathbf{l}, \mathbf{u};\mathbf{0}_n;\Sigma   \right)}$$
with

- $\Phi_n() $ the multivariate normal probability
- $\mathbf{l} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ vector with all elements are equal to $-\infty$
- $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ vector with all elements are equal to $b$
- $\mathbf{0}_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ vector of $0$
- $\Sigma$ is defined in $(4)$